# Pentaho Report Designer stacked percentage chart Y values

Tags: report, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I'm new to Pentaho, and I have a small problem I cannot seem find an answer to.   I'm running stock Pentaho 5.0.1 stable Report Designer. I have a bar chart that I have setup with a data source, everything there is showing/working correctly. I have changed the bar chart to a stacked percentage, and it stacks as expected.   The problem is the values of the chart show from 0.0 to 1.0 incrementing by 0.1. Aesthetically I'd prefer this range from 0% - 100%, but don't see a way to change how it displays.

I see some solutions related to CCC/CGG, but I'm not running any plugins. This is just a out of the box Bar Chart. Playing around with y-axis settings does change the scaling/min/max values but none of that changes the visual display of the chart from the calculated range of 0-1 to is percentage counter part.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the chart properties, go to Y-Axis and change the property y-tick-fmt-str (stands for Y ticks format string) to 0.0%.